# Value does not update the bean property

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm very new to JSF, I just started using it a few days ago and I'm trying to learn of  tutorials. But I can't tell why this isn't working.
I am using JSF 2.1 with PrimeFaces 3.5.
The problem is when I submit the form, the value is not updated property. Only last inputText is updated.

What am I missing?

View:

```
<h:body>

<h:form id="profilForm">


    <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
    <p:panel header="Profil" style="width: 460px;">

        <h:panelGrid id="loginPanel" columns="2">

            <h:outputLabel for="idPracownik" value="Id Pracownika" />

            <h:inputText id="idPracownik" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.idPracownik}" label="Id Pracownika"/>


            <p:outputLabel for="imie" value="Imię" />

            <p:inputText id="imie" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.imie}" label="Imię" />


            <h:outputLabel for="nazwisko" value="Nazwisko" />

            <p:inputText id="nazwisko" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.nazwisko}"  />


            <h:outputLabel for="kraj" value="Kraj" />

            <h:inputText id="kraj" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.kraj}" label="Kraj" />


            <h:outputLabel for="wojewodztwo" value="Województwo" />

            <h:inputText id="wojewodztwo" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.wojewodztwo}" label="Województwo" />



            <h:outputLabel for="miejscowosc" value="Miejscowość" />

            <h:inputText id="miejscowosc" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.miejscowosc}" label="Miejscowość" />


            <h:outputLabel for="adres" value="Adres" />

            <h:inputText id="adres" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.adres}" label="Adres" />



            <h:outputLabel for="kodPocztowy" value="Kod Pocztowy" />

            <h:inputText id="kodPocztowy" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.kodPocztowy}" label="Kod Pocztowy" />



            <h:outputLabel for="telefon" value="Telefon" />

            <h:inputText id="telefon" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.telefon}" label="Telefon" />


            <h:outputLabel for="email" value="E-mail" />

            <p:inputText id="email" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.email}" label="E-mail" />


            <h:outputLabel for="niepelnosprawnosc" value="Niepełnosprawność" />

            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="niepelnosprawnosc" value="#{pracownikControl.pracownik.niepelnosprawnosc}" label="Niepełnosprawność" />

        </h:panelGrid>

    </p:panel>

            <p:commandButton action="#{pracownikControl.updatePracownik()}" value="Zmień" />



</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
  public class Pracownik implements java.io.Serializable{

private int idPracownik;
private int idUzyt;
private int idPliki;
private String imie;
private String nazwisko;
private String poziomWyksz;
private Date dataUrodzenia;
private String adres;
private String kodPocztowy;
private String miejscowosc;
private String kraj;
private String wojewodztwo;
private int telefon;
private String email;
private boolean niepelnosprawnosc;



public Pracownik()
{

}

public Pracownik(int idPracownik, int idUzyt, int idPliki, String imie, String nazwisko, String poziomWyksz, Date dataUrodzenia, String adres, String kodPocztowy, String miejscowosc, String kraj, String wojewodztwo, int telefon, String email, boolean niepelnosprawnosc)
{
    this.idPracownik = idPracownik;
    this.idUzyt = idUzyt;
    this.idPliki = idPliki;
    this.imie = imie;
    this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    this.poziomWyksz = poziomWyksz;
    this.dataUrodzenia = dataUrodzenia;
    this.adres = adres;
    this.kodPocztowy = kodPocztowy;
    this.miejscowosc = miejscowosc;
    this.kraj = kraj;
    this.wojewodztwo = wojewodztwo;
    this.telefon = telefon;
    this.email = email;
    this.niepelnosprawnosc = niepelnosprawnosc;
}

public int getIdPracownik() {
    return idPracownik;
}

public void setIdPracownik(int idPracownik) {
    this.idPracownik = idPracownik;
}

public int getIdUzyt() {
    return idUzyt;
}

public void setIdUzyt(int idUzyt) {
    this.idUzyt = idUzyt;
}

public int getIdPliki() {
    return idPliki;
}

public void setIdPliki(int idPliki) {
    this.idPliki = idPliki;
}

public String getImie() {
    return imie;
}

public void setImie(String imie) {
    this.imie = imie;
}

public String getNazwisko() {
    return nazwisko;
}

public void setNazwisko(String nazwisko) {
    this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
}

public String getPoziomWyksz() {
    return poziomWyksz;
}

public void setPoziomWyksz(String poziomWyksz) {
    this.poziomWyksz = poziomWyksz;
}

public Date getDataUrodzenia() {
    return dataUrodzenia;
}

public void setDataUrodzenia(Date string) {
    this.dataUrodzenia = string;
}

public String getAdres() {
    return adres;
}

public void setAdres(String adres) {
    this.adres = adres;
}

public String getKodPocztowy() {
    return kodPocztowy;
}

public void setKodPocztowy(String kodPocztowy) {
    this.kodPocztowy = kodPocztowy;
}

public String getMiejscowosc() {
    return miejscowosc;
}

public void setMiejscowosc(String miejscowosc) {
    this.miejscowosc = miejscowosc;
}

public String getKraj() {
    return kraj;
}

public void setKraj(String kraj) {
    this.kraj = kraj;
}

public String getWojewodztwo() {
    return wojewodztwo;
}

public void setWojewodztwo(String wojewodztwo) {
    this.wojewodztwo = wojewodztwo;
}

public int getTelefon() {
    return telefon;
}

public void setTelefon(int telefon) {
    this.telefon = telefon;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public boolean isNiepelnosprawnosc() {
    return niepelnosprawnosc;
}

public void setNiepelnosprawnosc(boolean niepelnosprawnosc) {
    this.niepelnosprawnosc = niepelnosprawnosc;
}
```

}

Control:

```
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.text.ParseException;

    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import dao.PracownikDAO;
    import entity.Pracownik;

    @ManagedBean(name = "pracownikControl")
    @ViewScoped

    public class PracownikControl implements java.io.Serializable {

private Pracownik pracownik;
private Pracownik prac;

public PracownikControl()
{

}


public Pracownik getPracownik() throws SQLException, ParseException {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    System.out.println(pracownik.getTelefon());
     int id = (Integer)session.getAttribute("SesjaId");
    pracownik = PracownikDAO.wyswietl(id);

    return pracownik;
}

     public Pracownik updatePracownik() throws SQLException, ParseException {

FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
  int id = (Integer)session.getAttribute("SesjaId");
      pracownik = PracownikDAO.zmienDane(pracownik, id);
    return pracownik;
}

public void setPracownik(Pracownik pracownik) {
    this.pracownik = pracownik;
}
```

}

Comment: How have you determined that only the last field is updated?

Comment: I see it in my database and when the throw to console

Comment: First problem I see is your use of `@SessionScoped` and the logic you've placed in the constructor. You do realize that logic will be executed only once, for the entire lifetime of that session?

Comment: I changed sessions on viewScope but it did not change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code using the attributes `partialSubmit`, `ajax` and `process`:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{pracownikControl.updatePracownik()}" value="Zmień" ajax="true" partialSubmit="true" process="@form" />
```

You can use the id of component you have send to process too (your form, your panel, or other) like this:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{pracownikControl.updatePracownik()}" value="Zmień" ajax="true" partialSubmit="true" process=":profilForm" />
```

The attribute process can be use to say what scopes will be send for your method.

Answer (score 0):

You must update the profil form with all fields so you should use the "update" attribut in your command button. So, try this:

```
 <p:commandButton action="#{pracownikControl.updatePracownik()}" value="Zmień" 
  update=":profilForm" />
```

Comment: Its not really an answer if you don't explain why

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help but I added the code from my control file so maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem and i see that you forgot to say what you want to update. Just set the `update="@form"`. Because the `p:commandButton` is inside the form.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{pracownikControl.updatePracownik()}" value="Zmień"  update="@form" />
```